# Angular2 app in another angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a component that lists data in an angular2 app; When I click the list I want to load another angular 2 app according to the selected row in an application(from where I clicked) tab(I use nav bar).

Note: I am not talking about lazy loading of modules. We are using webpack, not system.js. I am not talking about multiple bootstapping. I want to lazy load an app.

Please help me to find out a solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering why it is you think you want to load another "application" and why simply lazy loading a module is not what you are really after. What exactly makes the result of the action a new "application"? I would suggest you consider that, since unless there is a "clear" distinction ( i.e new window / iframe ) then you are probably really talking about lazy loading a feature.

Comment: If this is really what you want, use an iframe :)